# Преобразовать дату и время к традиционному виду для локали

Tags: java, android

В android.

Как преобразовать дату и время к традиционному виду для локали?

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(new Date())
// Вывод: "08 февраля 2016г."
// Нужно например: "08 февраля 2016г. 10:25:17"
```

Необходимо получить еще и время. Вариант

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss")).format(new Date())
```

не предлагать, т.к. подходит не для всех локалей.

Comment: класс DateTimeFormat не пробовали?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, а где вы такой класс нашли?

Comment: наверное имелось ввиду DateTimeFormatter

Comment: да,именно DateTimeFormatter,  который находится в java.time.format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если бы вы хоть одним глазом посмотрели в [документацию](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html), то знали бы, что если вы замените  `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG)` на `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()`, то получите это:

> Dec 31, 1969 4:00:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

"Дата нас устраивает, но как прилепить к ней время" - конкатенация!

```
String d = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(new Date());
String t = (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date());
System.out.println(d+" "+t);
```

Итого

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date());
```

Comment: какой отличный.... велосипед :-(

Comment: В разных локалях формат времени тоже разный, так что такой вариант не подходит

Comment: Написать сразу про `SimpleDateFormat  .... M:1 MM:01 MMM:Jan MMMM:January MMMMM:J` не интересно.

Comment: С часами уже я промахнулся. Андроид немного не моя тема. Из того же SimpleDateFormat - `h: hour in am/pm (1-12)` зато `H: hour in day (0-23)`